# Как в плагине chartjs-plugin-datalabels v2.1.0 задать фотку?

Tags: javascript

Использую плагин 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels v2.1.0', для создания колеса удачи, нужно в графе labels заменить текст на img, как можно это сделать?

В обычном JS в строчке labels заданы значение '2', '3' и тд, хочу тогда засунуть img

```js
const spinWheel = document.getElementById("spinWheel");
    const spinBtn = document.getElementById("spin_btn");
    const text = document.getElementById("text");
    const spinValues = [
        { minDegree: 31, maxDegree: 60, value: 'Ноутбук игровой MSI Katana GF76 12UD-263RU' },
        { minDegree: 0, maxDegree: 30, value: 'Lush3 + Ridge x 1 + Микрофон HyperX Quadcast S' },
        { minDegree: 61, maxDegree: 90, value: 'Беззеркальная камера Canon EOS R50 Body' },
        { minDegree: 331, maxDegree: 360, value: 'Lovense Webcam + Domi 2' },
        { minDegree: 301, maxDegree: 330, value: '"Капуста"' },
        { minDegree: 271, maxDegree: 300, value: '"Картошка"' },
        { minDegree: 211, maxDegree: 240, value: 'Apple iPhone 15' },
        { minDegree: 241, maxDegree: 270, value: '"Морковь"' },
        { minDegree: 181, maxDegree: 210, value: 'Cougar Throne – кресло для геймеров' },
        {
            minDegree: 151,
            maxDegree: 180,
            value: "Сертификат ВБ",
        },
    ];
    
    
    const size = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10];
    var spinColors = [
        "#303032",
        "#303032",
        "#303032",
        "#303032",
        "#303032",
        "#303032",
        "#303032",
        "#303032",
        "#303032",
        "#303032",
        "#303032",
        "#303032",
    ];
    
    let spinChart = new Chart(spinWheel, {
        plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
        type: "pie",
        data: {
            labels: ['<img src="/img/11.png">', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: spinColors,
                data: size,
            }, ],
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            animation: { duration: 0 },
            plugins: {
                tooltip: false,
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                },
                datalabels: {
                    rotation: 90,
                    color: "#ffffff",
                    formatter: (_, context) => context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex],
                    font: { size: 24 },
                },
            },
        },
    });
    const generateValue = (angleValue) => {
        for (let i of spinValues) {
            if (angleValue >= i.minDegree && angleValue <= i.maxDegree) {
                text.innerHTML = `<p>Поздравляем, вы выиграли: <br> ${i.value} ! </p>`;
                spinBtn.disabled = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    };
    let count = 0;
    let resultValue = 101;
    spinBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // spinBtn.disabled = false;
        // text.innerHTML = `<p>Желаю Удачи!</p>`;
        let randomDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (355 - 0 + 1) + 0);
        let rotationInterval = window.setInterval(() => {
            spinChart.options.rotation = spinChart.options.rotation + resultValue;
            spinChart.update();
            if (spinChart.options.rotation >= 360) {
                count += 1;
                resultValue -= 5;
                spinChart.options.rotation = 0;
            } else if (count > 15 && spinChart.options.rotation == randomDegree) {
                generateValue(randomDegree);
                clearInterval(rotationInterval);
                count = 0;
                resultValue = 101;
            }
        }, 10);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>

<div>
  <canvas id="spinWheel"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="spin_btn">spin_btn</div>
<div id="text">text</div>
```